# How to cut peanut brittle

Tags: candy, cutting

I would like to be able to cut peanut brittle into neat squares. Everything I have tried does not result in a 'neat, straight cut', a quick Google search shows some very expensive 'industrial' machinery...but nothing for the 'home'.

Any good techniques for how to cut peanut brittle would be appreciated. I would also like a technique that would work after chocolate has been melted on top, although I could add the chocolate after the squares are cut.

Comment: Chocolate instead of the brittle mixture or in addition to?

Comment: Chocolate on top of peanut brittle (so 'in addition to')

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I'd probably try scoring it while it's not 100% set, letting it firm up, then breaking it ... then coating it in chocolate.  Option #2 is a band saw.  (although, it might gum up the saw)

Comment: A hack saw maybe.

Comment: I actually thought about a jig saw...as I haven't got a band saw.

Comment: I doubt that any of the "cutting while hot" techniques will work. The sugar portion is really sticky, and peanuts tend to be brittle. The commercial [Lance Peanut Bars](https://www.lance.com/peanut-bar/) are definitely cut while cold with some sort of saw toothed implement.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a finely serrated knife (I'm thinking like a dollar store steak knife). Move the knife back and forth many times, but apply little to no downward pressure that could cause the peanut brittle to fracture.

Comment: They're sometimes labeled as 'micro serrated'.  (and it'll slice through frozen spinach, and still cut tomatoes after going through a can!)

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet would be to try and cut it while it's still hot and hasn't set all the way. Once it cools completely, it's crystalline form is more likely to shatter than cut. For an example, see the strips in this pepita brittle recipe http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2008/11/pepita-brittle/

As for the chocolate, I would add it after cutting and letting it cool/harden all the way.

Answer (score 3):

[image: pizza cutter][image]

Here is a rolling cutter. its an effective way of cutting the peanut brittle. I also agree you have to cut it while its still warmish. This is how I would do it: bring the brittle to flat table. Add into steel frame, Roll the brittle out, with rolling pin. Until the level is even with the height of the steel frame. Remove steel frame and cut with rolling cutter in to desired size. Also note if you recipe is wrong or anything with your cooking procedure, it might be an added reason to not cutting it perfectly.

Comment: And also. Roast your peanuts for about 15 min on 140 degrees in the oven. This softens the peanuts and would make it easier to cut.

Comment: Can you provide a link for this item please?

Comment: I added one that would be easier to buy. Just a simple pizza cutter. www.biggreenegg.com. If your intrested in the rolling cutter i found it on www.tcfsales.com.